# Getting field values from another form to perform validation on the web in lotus notes

Tags: javascript, validation, lotus-notes

I have a radio button field on a lotus notes form (say main form). If it is selected as "Yes", a link gets unhidden. On click of this link, another form opens up. If in the radio button, "Yes" is selected in the main form, the contents in the second form must be filled. So I need to write a validation if the radio button field is "yes" and the field inside the second form is not filled, then it should show a popup asking to fill the field in the second form. How do I get the value of the field in the second form on the main form for me to perform the validation?

Comment: How do you display two forms at the same time? Which form is doing the validation?

Comment: The link opens the second form in another window. The main form is doing the validation.

Comment: It can be done using JavaScript, but it might be a lot of work to get it done properly. The approach seems quite complex, can't you simplify it? Why do you need 2 forms? Would it be possible to use only one form, and create or update the 2nd document internally? I assume this is an old-school Notes web application, not XPages.

Comment: The forms are already in use. I need this just for a validation

Comment: "just"... I'm sorry to say, but potential validation problems should have been solved before starting the development. The 2nd form is in a separate browser window, now can it be displayed without the 1st form, independently? Can it be closed by the user? Are both windows completely independent?

Comment: The second form cannot be displayed independently. There is a radio button on the first form and only if that is selected as "Yes", a link is unhidden which opens a second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally *cannot* do what you've described you want to do. The second (pop-up) form and its content no longer exist in the client (browser) context when you want to do validation on the first form's data. There are three possible ways to tackle the problem but only two of them are actually practical.

Let's dispense with the impractical method first. That would have the pop-up form write something back to its parent/opener, either as a JavaScript variable or as DOM content (a field outside of the Domino form or hidden element or some such) or, perhaps as a cookie value. Setting up the opener relationship reliably can be a problem cross-browser, but it is doable. The problem is that no matter how you do this, you have no guarantee that the value will be there when you need it (or expect it) except when the parent form is initially filled out. If the document is ever edited, you have no way of knowing whether or not the user has filled in the data on the pop-up. Anything you may have written to JS variables or the DOM during the initial session with the form only exist during the initial session. Cookies aren't permanent; they can be cleared by the user even if you try to give them eternal life via the expires value. No matter how you do it, you'd be telling anybody who has previously filled out the data you want that they need to fill it out again.

The second method would be to make a call back to the server to see if the pop-up form has been submitted and turned into a Notes document. That doesn't scale at all; even if everything is happening on a single server, there's no way to guarantee that the document you are looking for will have been written and indexed by the time you need it, and there is a time factor involved. If the user has already seen the validation nagging once, does what you tell them to do, and then gets the nag again, you're not making any friends.

The third method is to do everything you need to do on one form. (You can use CSS to do the pop-up if you're married to the pop-up idea.) And, you know, it really doesn't matter at all whether or not you would prefer to do it another way, it's the only way that will be reliable and make happy users. Yes, it will mean a little bit of extra work on your part. You're a developer - that's what you do for a living. You can even keep the structure of the existing application intact; WQO and WQS agents mean that you can glue documents together before sending them to your user, and pull them apart again before you save them. This is the only method that is guaranteed to be fast enough and reliable enough to be usable on the web.